# Best full-text search for google-app-engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, full-text-search

did you know the best full-text search on gae ?

thanks

Comment: It looks like this feature will be implemented soon. Issue's current status is 'started': http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=217

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297406/how-can-one-perform-full-text-search-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 3):

Read [this blog post](http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine) which details how to add full-text search to App Engine models.

It also details how to make only certain fields searchable, and turn on stemming.

Comment: This is what we use too, and it works great. Just hard to do paging and no substring matching.

Answer (score 3):

Now we can use *experimental* Search API:

> The Search API allows your application to perform Google-like searches
>   over structured data. You can search across several different types of
>   data (plain text, HTML, atom, numbers, dates, and geographic
>   locations). Searches return a sorted list of matching text. You can
>   customize the sorting and presentation of results.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

Early presentation: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/full-text-search.html

Answer (score -2):

[Google App Engine - Full Text Search](http://gae-text-search.appspot.com/)