# full-text search on bigtable

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, bigtable

any insight as to making/optimizing full-text searches on bigtable using java? best practices and such? how do u guys do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one perform full text search in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297406/how-can-one-perform-full-text-search-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic idea is to build an index as a list property from the text (stemmed and with stop words removed). To improve performance use "relation indexing" by moving the list property into a child entity. This prevents a potentially large list from being loaded as part of the default fetch group - you only need to query against. You'll have to use the low level api to do a keys only query taht will return the keys of the parent class which can then be used to fetch teh matching items.