# How should I do full-text searching on App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

What should I do for fast, full-text searching on App Engine with as little work as possible (and as little Java — I’m doing Python.)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one perform full text search in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297406/how-can-one-perform-full-text-search-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE has announced plans to offer full-text searching natively in the Datastore soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Whoosh with appengine in one of my recent project and it seems to work fine. Have a look at  https://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine

Comment: As recently as last summer, people had been saying Whoosh didn’t work on App Engine.  It’s all groovy now?

Comment: About how many words are in your index? How long do searches take to complete?